# адаптивность в bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="photo_list" src="/new.jpg" width="400"/>
        <div class="caption">
            <h3><span class="badge">new</span>categoryyyy</h3>
            <p>создать новую категорию</p>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-list" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-new_catgr">создать
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

как сделать, чтоб текст и кнопка не выходили за рамки при уменьшении окна браузера [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте для `.thumbnail` атрибут `overflow-x: hidden;`, тогда элементы внутри не будут вылезать наружу блока.

Но это решение в лоб. Проблема ведь в другом. У вас колонки на мобильном устройстве получаются слишком узкие.

Используйте классы `col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3`, тогда на экранах побольше у вас будет по 2-3-4 колонки в ряд, а на мобильных устройствах колонки будут в столбик.

Answer (score 1):

Если важно сохранить несколько колонок, то можно установить в CSS `min-width` для `div.container`.